# Integral $\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-\frac{x}{a}} dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Improper integral of

$$\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x/a} \, dx$$

I tried to do it by using Partial Integral and looked for the trend of $a$ and $n$ but it's confusing and I cannot finish it

Is there any other method to solve this? (I think of the Laplace Transform, but cannot find any relation)

Comment: First use $y = x/a$ then this is a known Laplace.

Comment: Alternatively, this can be easily turned into the Gamma function.

Comment: $$ \int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x/a} \, dx = a^{n+1} \int_0^\infty \left( \frac x a \right)^n e^{-x/a} \, \frac{dx} a = a^{n+1} \int_0^\infty u^n e^{-u} \, du. $$

Comment: I tried to compare the question with lapace transform definition and found that if I let $\frac{1}{a} = s$ then I'll get the laplace transform on $x^n$ so the laplace transform of $x^n$ is $\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$ so I replace $s$ with $\frac{1}{a}$ Is that valid?

Comment: @RexSolus , yes.

Comment: After substituting $y=x/a$, this problem is same as [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378736/evaluate-the-integral-int-e-xxn-dx/2378819#2378819). In this link you can have $4$ answers, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-\frac{x}{a}}\,dx
&\overset{u=x/a}{=} \int_0^{\infty} (au)^ne^{-u}\,(a\,du)\\
&= a^{n+1}\int_0^{\infty}u^{(n+1)-1}e^{-u}\,du \\
&= a^{n+1}\Gamma(n+1) = a^{n+1}n!
\end{align}
if $n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x/a} \, dx = a^{n+1} \int_0^\infty \left( \frac x a \right)^n e^{-x/a} \, \frac{dx} a = a^{n+1} \int_0^\infty u^n e^{-u} \, du = a^{n+1} \Gamma(n+1). $$

If you know that $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty u^n e^{-u} \,du = n!$ for non-negative integer $n,$ then you can use that here. You can show that by integrating by parts and getting $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty u^n e^{-u} \, du = n \int_0^\infty u^{n-1} e^{-u} \, du.$ Iterate that to get the result. In the process, you'll see
$$
\int_0^\infty u^n e^{-u} \, du = \Big[ \cdots\cdots \Big]_0^\infty  + n \int_0^\infty u^{n-1} e^{-u} \, du
$$
and you can use L'Hopital's rule to show that that first term is $0.$