# Proving $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n\mathrm dx}{e^{nx}-1}= \frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^n}\zeta{(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n\mathrm dx}{e^{nx}-1}= \frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^n}\zeta{(n+1)}$$

I have evaluated the integral by turning denominator into a geometric series and by switching integral and summation. However, my actual answer was in terms of factorials and I had assumed that $n\in\mathbb N$ while solving to make it into this form. Using an online calculator, I had verified it for $n=1,2,3$.

**Questions:**
Can we solve it by any other method ?
For what (if any) does it holds for some non-natural $n$ ?

Comment: This approach is correct. $\Gamma(n)$ will always make sense if $n>0$, this identity is always correct if $n>0$. You should find that your working will, well, work, if $n$ is not integer

Comment: @FShrike Thanks. But as said in question, I actually arrived at answer in factorial form i.e. $\frac{\zeta{(n+1)(n-1)!}}{n^n}$for simplicity of evaluation and only switched to gamma later for a neat look.

Comment: Why wouldn't your approach work if $n$ is not an integer ?

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.5

Comment: @SineoftheTime Thanks , but it don't match up with this. Notice the power to which $e$ is raised to. Instead, it's more related to my already closed question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4718584/1020656

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Because this integral : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3768355/1020656 comes up in my integral as an intermediate step which holds for $n\in \mathbb N$ as per answer.

Comment: @An_Elephant You’re missing the point. By very definition of the gamma function it’s easy to show, substituting $u=ax$, that $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-ax}dx=\Gamma(s)/a^s$. That’s why I commented your approach should work for non integer $n$, since that integral identity holds for non integer (positive) $n$

Comment: Well, then just substitute $y=\alpha x$ in this integral, and you will directly recognise $\Gamma$.

Comment: @FShrike But how can this be done here. The denominator here is not only $e^{\alpha x}$ but there is also a $1$ in addition to it.

Comment: @An_Elephant Well, presumably in your working you arrived at a geometric series with summands of the correct form - no extra $1$s

Comment: @An_Elephant can't you substituite ?

Comment: @FShrike Oops, I misunderstood you that you are saying to substitute before switching integral and summation. Sorry.

Comment: @SineoftheTime Yes I get it.

Comment: @An_Elephant By taking $t=xn$, your integral becomes $$
\frac{1}{{n^{n + 1} }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^n }}{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}}{\rm d}t} .
$$ Now use the result in your [closed question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718584/int-0-infty-fracxkex-1-mathrm-dx-zetak1k).

Comment: @Gary Thanks. I didn't thought about the substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a slight extension of [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem). I will include a proof below.

> Assume $f$ and $h$ have an expansion of the form,
> $$f(x)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty h(mx),\quad h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\varphi(k)}{k!}(-x)^k,$$ then the Mellin
> transform of $f(x)$ is given by, $$\int_0^{+\infty} x^{n-1}f(x)\
> dx=\Gamma(n)\zeta(n)\varphi(-n).$$

In our case,
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{e^{nx}-1}=\frac{1}{e^{nx}}\frac{1}{1-e^{-nx}}=\frac{1}{e^{nx}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-knx}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-knx}$$
where,
$$h(kx)=e^{-knx}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{n^m}{m!}(-kx)^m$$
hence the Mellin transform,
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{nx}-1}\ dx=\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)n^{-s}$$
take $s=n+1$,
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{e^{nx}-1}\ dx=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{n^{n+1}}\zeta(n+1)=\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^n}\zeta(n+1).$$

> *Proof.*
> By Ramanujan's master theorem,
> $$\int_0^{+\infty}x^{n-1} h(x)\ dx=\Gamma(n)\varphi(-n)$$
> subbing $x\mapsto mx$,
> $$m^{n}\int_0^{+\infty} x^{n-1}h(mx)\ dx=\Gamma(n)\varphi(-n)$$
> rearranging and summing over $m\in\mathbb{N}$,
> $$\int_0^{+\infty} x^{n-1}\sum_{m=1}^\infty h(mx)\ dx=\sum_{m=1}^\infty m^{-n}\Gamma(n)\varphi(-n)=\Gamma(n)\zeta(n)\varphi(-n)$$
> hence, $$\int_0^{+\infty} x^{n-1}f(x)\ dx=\Gamma(n)\zeta(n)\varphi(-n).$$

Comment: Awesome!! I will need to tuck this away into my integral solving toolbox.

Comment: @K.defaoite. If you like this, you might also like my question on generalizing the master theorem. (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4744295/1141581)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, we can use generating functions and bracket integration.

By the generating function for [Bernoulli numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html) $B_k$,
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k}{k!}x^k$$
we have,
$$\frac{x^n}{e^{nx}-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_kn^k}{k!n}x^{k+n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}n^kk\zeta(1-k)}{k!n}x^{k+n-1}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\phi_kn^{k-1}k\zeta(1-k)x^{k+n-1}$$
here I used [relation (43)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html) and the indicator $\phi_k$,
$$B_k=(-1)^{k+1}k\zeta(1-k),\quad \phi_k=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!},$$
re-expressing the integral as a bracket series,
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^{nx}-1}\ dx=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\phi_kn^{k-1}k\zeta(1-k)\langle k+n\rangle$$
which assigns the value,
$$-n^{-n-1}{(-n)}\zeta(1+n)\Gamma(n)=\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^n}\zeta(1+n).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=nx\implies dt=ndx$, we have:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n\mathrm dx}{e^{nx}-1}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)^n\cdot\frac{1}{e^t-1}\cdot \frac1n dt=\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{e^t-1}dt$$
We are going to use power series expansion of the denominator, so:
$$\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{e^t-1}dt=\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n\cdot e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}dt$$
In particular:
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-t}}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}e^{-it}$$
So:
$$\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty}t^n\cdot e^{-t}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}e^{-it}dt=\frac{1}{n^{n-1}}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^n\cdot e^{-t(1+i)}dt=\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+i}\right)^{n+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^ne^{-s}ds=\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\cdot \zeta(n+1)\cdot\Gamma(n+1)$$
Using $\Gamma(n+1)=n\cdot\Gamma(n)$, we  can conclude:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{e^{nx}-1}dx=\frac{1}{n^n}\cdot\zeta(1+n)\cdot\Gamma(n)$$

Comment: Though the idea being highlighted in comments, thanks for outlining the steps.